# module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'write_graph'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

while I see many problems with the module '`tensorflow._api.v2.train`' I could not find something that will solve my problem. Any ideas here? is there something about version `2.0` of TensorFlow? Should I use some other version such as `1.15` perhaps?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim)))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(64, recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.0015), input_shape=(timesteps,input_dim)))


model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0025), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)

model.save('model1.h5')
print("Saved model to disk")

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model=load_model('model1.h5')
model.summary()

from keras import backend as k
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph, optimize_for_inference_lib
import tensorflow as tf

input_node_name = ['lstm_1_input']
output_node_name = 'output/Softmax'
model_name='har_model

tf.train.write_graph(k.get_session().graph_def, 'models', model_name + '_graph.pbtxt')
saver=tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(k.get_session(), 'models/'+model_name + '.chkp')

freeze_graph.freeze_graph('models/'+model_name + '_graph.pbtxt', None, False, 'models/'+model_name+'.chkp',
                         output_node_name, 'save/restore_all', 'save/Const:0', 'models/frozen_' + model_name + '.pb', True, "")
```

Comment: did you find a way to produce .pbtxt file in tn tensorflow2?